# Where can I find a SWIFT form in HTML?

Tags: html, templates, accounting, banking, swift-mt

I'm developing a banking/accounting system and want to make possible printing a `SWIFT` (Society for Worldwide Interbank Financial Telecommunication) payment order.

Does anybody meet a `HTML` template of such form?

Comment: Is this about a template that contains all necessary field, or a layout template with exact placement of all fields to make a printout?

Comment: @Pekka: Rather a layout template to fill with the data and print it

Comment: If you can't find any, are you also interested in resources on how to build printable HTML in CSS? PDF would be a more reliable way to do this, though.

Answer (score 3):

For which message type? There are so many SWIFT messages (MT350, MT103, ...) out there. You probably want a MT202?

Maybe this can help you on your way: http://www.ubs.com/1/ShowMedia/bank_for_banks/offering/securities/processing?contentId=28371&name=SWIFT_ForGuiMee_e4GzD.pdf